# Get generic Type out of ICollection

Tags: dictionary, generics, reflection

I'm using the following method but on a `Dictionary` it returns the `TKey`.
`Dictionary` implements `ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>` so how can i get 
`KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>`?

```
public static Type GetCollectionGenericType( this Type type )
{
    foreach( Type interfaceType in type.GetInterfaces() )
    {
        if( interfaceType.IsGenericType &&
            interfaceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof( ICollection<> ) )
        {
            return type.GetGenericArguments()[ 0 ];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first generic argument of `Dictionary<>` is `TKey` and that is what your code returns. You have to change your code to get first generic argument of the `interfaceType` you are looping through.

```
public static Type GetCollectionGenericType( Type type )
{
    foreach( Type interfaceType in type.GetInterfaces() )
    {
        if( interfaceType.IsGenericType && interfaceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof( ICollection<> ) )
        {
            return interfaceType.GetGenericArguments()[ 0 ];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```